# cannot find module 'passport-local' error

Tags: node.js, module, passport.js

am using passport in node.js

in my app.js

```
var passport = require('passport')

require('./config/passport').boot(passport, config)
```

in passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
```

run the app and i get this error message

```
module.js:340
    throw err;

error:Cannot find module 'passport-local'
      at Object.<anonymous> <F:\work\config\passport.js:2:21>
```

i install the passport in F:\work\node_modules.

even if i put the

```
 var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
```

right under the

```
 var passport = require('passport')
```

i still get the same error

any idea why?

Answer (score 25):

Have you installed passport-local module?

`npm install passport-local`

Comment: damn!i thought the passport-local is part of passport thanx

Comment: Honestly, this is like a bug for Passport. Their documentation should really mention that you need to include passport-local as well.

Comment: I think the idea that you are requiring it separately is supposed to indicate that it is a separate module. Nonetheless, I came here to double check.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it:

Check your `package.json` file.
If it does not exist, you need to init your project in the same folder where you wrote your main JS file (`server.js` or `index.js` or however you want).

```
$ sudo npm init
```

and when installing npm modules, remeber to save them in package file:

```
$ sudo npm install passport-local --save
```

I solved in this way.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
npm i --save-dev @types/passport-local
```